# Django 1.8 Slider Image not displaying

Tags: python, django, image, django-templates, django-views

In Django 1.8, I can upload images and they are saved on the path that they should, but when I add `<img src="{{ slider.Image.url }}" alt="Slider" />` to template, the images are not displaying. If I want to see only the image like this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/slider/1.jpg` in the url the image does appear. But when I go to the home page `http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/` it only show me the alt.

Here is my dir tree:

```
 - home
 - static
 - static/
         css
         images
               slider
         js
```

The images placed properly in slider. CSS and Js working properly.

Here is my settings file

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'home'
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

MEDIA_URL = (
    'static/'
)

MEDIA_ROOT = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
)
```

When I use `static_root` the problem get more serious nothing worked.

Here is my models in home for slider

```
class Slider(models.Model):
    ImageName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/slider")
```

Here is my main urls

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url, patterns
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^home/', include('home.urls')),
]

from django.conf import settings
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': False}),
)
```

Here  is my home app urls

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.slider, name='slider',)
]
```

Here is my template source

```
{% for slider in sliders %}

    <li class="item"><img src="{{ slider.Image.url }}" alt="Slider" /><span class="overlay1"></span></li>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What is the value of `{{ slider.Image.url }}`? Inspect the `img`'s source and see for its value.

Comment: <img src="static/images/slider/1.jpg">

Comment: <li class="item"><img src="/static/{{ slider.Image }}" alt="Slider" /><span class="overlay1"></span></li>

Comment: Sorry PIP wasn't Installed.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't mix static and media files. Static files are CSS, JavaScript, Images and other files that comes in package with your app, so it can work properly or to look nice.

Media files are files uploaded from website or just files associated with some objects in database.

That files shouldn't be mixed.

Also, `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATICFILES_DIRS` shouldn't point at same directory. All files from `STATICFILES_DIRS` and files from `static` directories inside each app will be copied or linked into `STATIC_ROOT` when `./manage.py collectstatic` is executed.

Django development server by default won't serve any media files, if you want them to be served, add to your main `urls.py` file:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Brother everything is working but the image is not displaying in the template source. I am trying your solution now but I have tried all stackoverflow answers. Thanks for the replay.

Comment: I have changed my models to keep my files to media/images dir. But I have the same problem.